# Cannot Invoke Initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '()'

Tags: ios, swift3

I am using [CVCalendar](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) in project and I have updated the Xcode to 8.0 Beta. The problem is I am receiving an error in one file saying:

> 1) Cannot Invoke Intializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type
>   '()'
>
> 2) Argument labels '(body:)' do not match any available overloads

```
// MARK: - SequenceType

private var storage = [T]()

extension CVSet: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<T> {
        var power = 0
        let nextClosure : () -> T? = {

            (power < self.count) ? self.storage[Int(power += 1)] : nil //Getting error here self.storage[Int(power += 1)]
        }
        return AnyIterator(body: nextClosure)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`+=`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Operators/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/opfunc/s:ZFsoi2peFTRSiSi_T_) operator has a type such as `(Int, Int) -> _`, meaning it's return type is `_` / `()` / `void`. I.e., the function doesn't return anything.

Thus, the expression `Int(power += 1)` is the same as `Int()`, which is not valid.

This was done to prevent nasty side effects hidden in large expressions. Try instead:

```
if (power < self.count) {
    power += 1
    return self.storage[power]
}
else {
    return nil
}
```